# Counting live neighbors in conway's game of life not working

Tags: python

So I am creating conway's game of life in python. The rules are

Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies
Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.
Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies.
Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell.

I can't figure out why first of all, my liveNeighbors counter is printing wrong sometimes, and also the board never changes.

```
def nextIteration(board):    
    newBoard =[]
    for i in board:
        tempList = []
        for j in i:
            tempList.append(j)
        newBoard.append(tempList)
    print(newBoard)
    for row in range(len(newBoard)):
        for column in range(len(newBoard[row])):
            liveNeighbors = 0
            if (row - 1 >= 0) and (column - 1 >= 0):
                if newBoard[row - 1][column - 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (row - 1 >= 0):
                if newBoard[row - 1][column] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (row - 1 >= 0) and (column + 1 < len(newBoard[row])):
                if newBoard[row - 1][column + 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (column - 1 >= 0):
                if newBoard[row][column - 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (column + 1) < len(newBoard[row]):
                 if newBoard[row][column + 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (row + 1) < len(newBoard[row]):
                if newBoard[row + 1][column - 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (row + 1 < len(newBoard[row])):
                if newBoard[row + 1][column] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if (row + 1 < len(newBoard[row]) and column + 1 < len(newBoard[row])):
                if newBoard[row + 1][column + 1] == "X":
                    liveNeighbors += 1
            if newBoard[row][column] == "X":
                if liveNeighbors < 2 or liveNeighbors > 3:
                    board[row][column] == "0"
            if newBoard[row][column] == "0":
                if liveNeighbors == "3":
                    board[row][column] == "X"
            print(liveNeighbors, end="")
            print()
    return board


def printBoard(board):
   for row in board:
       for item in row:
           print(item, end="")
       print()


def main():
    rows = input("Please enter number of rows: ")
    columns = input("Please enter number of columns: ")
    print()
    cellRow = 0
    cellRows = []
    cellColumns = []
    total = 0
    #the cellRow and cellColumn will contain all of the inputted rows                                                        
    #and columns connected by the index value                                                                                
    while cellRow != "q":
        cellRow = input("Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): ")
        if cellRow != "q":
                cellColumn = input("Please enter a column for that cell: ")
                cellRows.append(cellRow)
                cellColumns.append(cellColumn)
                total = total + 1
                print()
        else:
            print()
    board = []
    #boardTemp will hold a list that contains one row of the entire board                                                    
    boardTemp = []
    for i in range(int(rows)):
        boardTemp.append("0")
    for i in range(int(columns)):
        board.append(boardTemp[:])
    for i in range(total):
        temp = i
        board[int(cellRows[temp - 1])][int(cellColumns[temp - 1])] = "X"
    iterations = input("How many iterations should I run? ")
    print()
    print("Starting Board:")
    print()
    printBoard(board)
    iterationNumber = 1
    for i in range(int(iterations)):
        board = nextIteration(board)
        print("Iteration", iterationNumber,":")
        printBoard(board)
        iterationNumber += 1
main()
```

Prints:

```
Please enter number of rows: 5
Please enter number of columns: 5

Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): 3
Please enter a column for that cell: 3

Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): 2
Please enter a column for that cell: 3

Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): 4
Please enter a column for that cell: 3

Please enter the row of a cell to turn on (or q to exit): q

How many iterations should I run? 1

Starting Board:

00000
00000
000X0
000X0
000X0
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', 'X', '0']]
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
2
1
2
0
0
3
2
3
0
0
2
1
2
Iteration 1 :
00000
00000
000X0
000X0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking equality instead of assigning in this part of your `nextIteration` function:

```
        if newBoard[row][column] == "X":
            if liveNeighbors < 2 or liveNeighbors > 3:
                board[row][column] == "0" # Here
        if newBoard[row][column] == "0":
            if liveNeighbors == "3":
                board[row][column] == "X" # And here
```

`board[row][column] == "0"` should be `board[row][column] = "0"` etc.  Currently the line evaluates to `True`, and then that value is immediately discarded, and no state change occurs.